# Non Super Admins users can't login?

Tags: control-panel, login

I had client of mine contact me this morning about them not being able to login to the CP of the site. I thought at first it was a cookie/session issue, but after having them clear their browser history numerous times, try other browsers, etc., it was doing the same. So I asked for their password and tried locally myself and the same thing was happening, it would just redirect back to the login page. However, I'm able to login since my user is in the **Super Admin** group. Anyone else experience this before or know of any fixes?

EE 2.7.2

Comment: Stupid questions first - but what group did you put them in? and what settings did you setup for access to control panel? Second stupid question - is there a redirect string as part of the login url... this can scupper things.

Comment: I isolated the issue. See answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit to be Zoo Flexible Admin. More [here](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-flexible-admin/viewthread/11182)